# How to replace value of r's dataframe column with other dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have following data frame in R

```
Amount   Transaction_Type
62.81          1
6.66           2
19.9           3
24.02          2
24.02          2
45.2           1
19.76          3
```

The other dataframe I have is following

```
Transaction        Transaction_Type   
  CARD                    1
  CASH                    2
  VOUCHER                 3
```

I want to replace Transaction values in the first dataframe,so it will look like following

```
Amount      Transaction_Type
62.81          CARD
6.66           CASH
19.9           VOUCHER
24.02          CASH
24.02          CASH
45.2           CARD
19.76          VOUCHER
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not simply `df1$Transaction_Type <- df2[match(df1$Transaction_Type, df2$Transaction_Type), 1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
df1$Transaction_Type <- df2$Transaction[match(df1$Transaction_Type, 
                                df2$Transaction_Type)]
df1$Transaction_Type
#[1] "CARD"    "CASH"    "VOUCHER" "CASH"    "CASH"    "CARD"    "VOUCHER"
```

---

Or another `base R` option is

```
unname(with(df2, setNames(Transaction, Transaction_Type))[as.character(df1$Transaction_Type)])
#[1] "CARD"    "CASH"    "VOUCHER" "CASH"    "CASH"    "CARD"    "VOUCHER"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do using the `merge` method of R. In your example:

```
a=data.frame(
   "Amount"=c(62.81,6.66,19.9,24.02,24.02,45.2,19.76),
   "Transaction_Type"=c(1,2,3,2,2,1,3))
t=data.frame(
   "Transaction"=c("CARD","CASH","VOUCHER"),
   "Transaction_Type"=c(1,2,3))
```

if you run the following: `merge(a,t,by="Transaction_Type")` you will output the structure you want:

```
  Transaction_Type Amount Transaction
1                1  62.81        CARD
2                1  45.20        CARD
3                2   6.66        CASH
4                2  24.02        CASH
5                2  24.02        CASH
6                3  19.90     VOUCHER
7                3  19.76     VOUCHER
```

Of course afterwards, you can keep the columns you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first dataframe is `df1`, and the second is `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "Transaction_Type") %>% select(-Transaction_Type)

#  Amount Transaction
#1  62.81        CARD
#2   6.66        CASH
#3  19.90     VOUCHER
#4  24.02        CASH
#5  24.02        CASH
#6  45.20        CARD
#7  19.76     VOUCHER
```